# Need help understanding .Select method C#

Tags: c#, oop, select, var, paradigms

I am having difficulties understandting what type of statement this is and how to use the .select method.

```
 var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\mycsvfil3.csv")
           .Select(l => new
           {
               myIdentiafication= int.Parse(l.Split(',')[0].Trim()),
               myName= l.Split(',')[1].Trim()
           }
             ).OrderBy(i => i.Id);
```

any help is appreciated!

Comment: Wait a minute. Does that compiles? `i.Id`? `i` is an anonymous type which doesn't define `Id` property.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel No it won't compile.

Comment: @ siram & Adam , -> yeah it compiled but i do see the error

Comment: @The---Doctor If there was a compilation error, then it didn't compile...

Comment: Then why can/does it compile?? if    i is an anonymnous type that does not define the    Id property  why does it work??

Answer (score 2):

This is a LINQ query. [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *projects* each line from file into anonymous object with properties `myIdentiafication` and `myName`. Then you sort sequence of anonymous objects with [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But you should select property which exists in anonymous object. E.g. `myIdentiafication` because there is no `id` property:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\mycsvfil3.csv") // get sequence of lines
                .Select(l => new {
                    myIdentiafication = int.Parse(l.Split(',')[0].Trim()),
                    myName= l.Split(',')[1].Trim()
                 }).OrderBy(i => i.myIdentiafication);
```

NOTE: To avoid parsing each line twice, you can use query syntax with [introducing new range variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx):

```
var lines = from l in File.ReadLines(@"c:\temp\mycsvfil3.csv")
            let pair = l.Split(',')
            let id = Int32.Parse(pair[0].Trim())
            orderby id
            select new {
                Id = id,
                Name = pair[1].Trim()
            };
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Enumerable.Select` method is an extension method for an `IEnumerable<T>` type. It takes a `Func<TSource, TResult>` that allows you to take in your `IEnumerable<T>` items and *project* them to something else, such as a property of the type, or a new type. It makes heavy use of generic type inference from the compiler to do this without `<>` everywhere.

In your example, the `IEnumerable<T>` is the `string[]` of lines from the file. The `Select` func creates an **anonymous type** (also making use of generic type inference) and assigns some properties based on splitting each line `l`, which is a `string` from your enumerable.

`OrderBy` is another `IEnumerable<T>` extension method and proceeds to return an `IEnumerable<T>` in the order based on the expression you provide.

`T` at this point is the anonymous type from the `Select` with two properties (`myIdentiafication` and `myName`), so the `OrderBy(i => i.Id)` bit *won't compile.* It can be fixed:

```
.OrderBy(i => i.myIdentiafication);
```

Comment: Thanks that does help me understand it much better and @ Sergey thinking of it as a db query makes it much simpler for me.

Answer (score 0):

From each string returned by `ReadLines` create an anonymous object with two properties (`myIdentiaficiation` and `myName`). Within the Select the context variable `l` represents a single line from the set returned by `ReadLines`.